# Override theme_form for drupal 7

Tags: drupal, themes, overriding

I am trying to override theme_form function by `uc_attribute` module.
The function is `theme_uc_attribute_add_to_cart` which themes the attributes of drupal ubercart.
Is there a way to override this function in my module. i want to overide in my function because i dont want to touch this function as per drupal standards.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

you can override it in your themes template.php file by using the following syntax
THEMENAME_uc_attribute_add_to_cart

Replace THEMENAME with the name of the theme.